# inaccessible when using nth in title expansion with fancyhdr and biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, fancyhdr

I really hate that I have to ask questions whenever I hit a problem with Latex, instead of fixing them myself. But there you go - MWE as `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[super]{nth} % ordinals
\usepackage[level]{datetime}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields

\begin{document}

\title{Oh, Latex \nth{1}...}
\author{Bob Whoever}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\formatdate{14}{02}{2017}}
\date{\mydate}%{\today}%
\makeatletter
\edef\tmptitle{\@title}% must edef here, then it is present in \fancyhead
\fancyhead[L]{\small \tmptitle}
\makeatother
\maketitle

What to do when Latex croaks with the "inaccessible"? Some people have said:

\blockquote[{\cite{mps01}}]{
Well, one can just look at error log - unfortunately, it is all too cryptic there...
}

\clearpage

\printbibliography %biblatex only

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mps01,
  title={Looking into (error) logs of [the] Latex},
  url={http://www.example.com/just_example},
  author={Someone Else}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\end{document}
```

When you run `pdflatex test.tex` the first time, it passes.

Then, when you run `biber test`, it passes.

Then, when you run `pdflatex test.tex` the second time, it crashes with:

```
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.49 \end{document}

? X
```

Wow, thanks for the most unhelpful error message!

I can tell you now - the problem is me using `\nth` in `\title` AND using `\edef\tmptitle...` AND using a biblatex bibliography; if either of these is not present, then the bloody error does not occur.

So, how can I use `\nth` in `\title`, such that I can use `\@title` in `\fancyhead` WHILE using a `biblatex` bibliography? And what ended up being "inaccessible" here?

Comment: biblatex is not relevant. Its only effect here is that it creates a second page at the second compilation (when the bibliography is no longer empty) and so reveals the problem of your header definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

Use

```
 \let\tmptitle\@title
```

### Analysis

Your problem is

```
\edef\tmptitle{\@title}
```

as `\nth` is not expandable nor robust. One should not in most cases `\edef` 'general' text, but rather use `\protected@edef`

```
\protected@edef\tmptitle{\@title}
```

This will fix the issue though the text of `\tmptitle` isn't quite what one would expect:

```
> \tmptitle=macro:
->Oh, Latex 1\relax \protect \textsuperscript  {st}....
```

One could make `\nth` engine-robust

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\nth
```

as you can then use it safely in an `\edef` and will get

```
> \tmptitle=macro:
->Oh, Latex \nth {1}....
```

However, you really want to simply make a copy of `\@title` here, which can be done using `\let`

```
\let\tmptitle\@title
```

and which works with no other 'fiddling'.

Comment: The *real* solution is the last one, which should better be at the top.

Comment: @egreg Well `\let` is a TeX primitive whereas `\protected@edef` is a LaTeX kernel command, so one could argue about that (also as you know I think most commands should be engine-robust)

Comment: Well, nobody should be using `nth` anyway. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in `\edef\tmptitle{\@title}`.

You can solve it more generally by making LaTeX not forget `\@title` after having done `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[super]{nth} % ordinals
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\global\let\@title\@empty}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\global\let\@author\@empty}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{\small\@title}
\makeatother
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}

\title{Oh, Latex \nth{1}...}
\author{Bob Whoever}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\mbox{} % let's produce a new page

\end{document}
```

An indirect strategy may be simpler:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[super]{nth} % ordinals
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields
\fancyhead[L]{\small\papertitle}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\newcommand{\papertitle}{Oh, Latex \nth{1}...}

\begin{document}

\title{\papertitle}
\author{Bob Whoever}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\mbox{} % let's produce a new page

\end{document}
```